# Using objective-c to build a cisco jabber client,but error message pop up:"does not contain bitcode"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xmpp, bitcode

I download JabberGuest SDK for iOS, and follow the https://developer.cisco.com/site/jabber-guestsdk/learn/tutorials/v10_6_9/#steps28 this guild. I am trying to create a new demo application using storyboards by using the CJGuestCallViewController.

But a error message pop up:

`JabberGuest.framework/JabberGuest(CJGuestCallViewController.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I try to switch the Enable Bitcode to "NO", which makes about other 60 errors. I also try to add jabberGuest.framework into Compiles Sources and Link Binary in Build Phases. It doesn't work either. I try everything I can find online, include clean the Derived Data in Locations of Preferences. Restart the computer. I still stuck here for whole day.

Need help!

I'm using xcode 8.1.
Jabber Guest for iOS - 10.6.11

If you need more information let me know.

Any help would be appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: I find something. When I try to init a viewController with the viewController they gave. There will have "bitcode" issue .  such as

"CJGuestCallViewController *newView = [[CJGuestCallViewController alloc]init];
"

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem with this:

1. In Project Build Settings: In the Build Active Architecture Only
   section,select No.
2. In the Valid Architectures section, enter armv7 arm64 if your app is an universal binary, otherwise choose either armv7 or arm64.
3. In the Other Linker Flags section, add -ObjC.
4. Must have the C++ Standard Library build setting set to libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support).
5. In the Enable Bitcode section, choose the No.

The issue is gone!